# LibGDX: Scene2d layout problems

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

Hello I have a problem with a Table layout:
With this code I got a weird spaceing beetween the two tables.

```
public class ItemList extends Table {
    private final float TABLE_PADDING = 5.0f;
    private Table layout;

    private Array<Image> images = new Array<Image>();

    public ItemList(Skin skin) {
        super(skin);
        this.setBackground("bg_dark_grey");

        layout = new Table(skin);

        TextField itemSearch = new TextField("", skin);
        itemSearch.setMessageText("Search");
        this.add(itemSearch).pad(TABLE_PADDING).fillX().row();

        ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane(layout, skin);
        this.add(scrollPane);
    }

    public void addItems(TextureAtlas items) {
        // Add a cell to layout for every image.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The class is a table (extends Table) and layout is a table

Comment: Sounds like a screenshot would be handy here.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly user **debug()** to see tables boundaries

```
    ...
    super(skin);
    this.setBackground("bg_dark_grey");

    this.debug();

    ...

    layout = new Table(skin);

    layout.debug();

    ...
```

secondly I'm pretty sure that **pad** added to **itemSearch** makes the spaceing - please check